# Visibility InternalUsers is not permitted for this linked record only in Test context

Tags: trigger, unit-test, contentdocumentlink

I am receiving the following message when trying to insert a ContentDocumentLink in a trigger but only in test context :

> Visibility InternalUsers is not permitted for this linked record

I checked that the LinkedEntityId is valid, and I also looked it up but there is no great documentation about it, I only found that you need to have communities enabled in order to use that 'Visibility=InternalUsers' which is the case for me.

Here is the trigger handler class :

```
...
for(ContentVersion oneV : [SELECT ContentDocumentId, CreatedBy.Contact.AccountId, CreatedBy.AccountId
        FROM ContentVersion
        WHERE Id IN :docsMap.keySet() AND IsLatest = true
        AND CreatedBy.Profile.Name = :System.Label.My_Profile_Name]){
            if(!docIdsToAccountsIds.containsKey(oneV.ContentDocumentId)){
                docIdsToAccountsIds.put(oneV.ContentDocumentId, oneV.CreatedBy.AccountId);
                docLinksToCreate.add(new ContentDocumentLink(
                ContentDocumentId = oneV.ContentDocumentId,
                LinkedEntityId = (String.isNotBlank(oneV.CreatedBy.AccountId) ? oneV.CreatedBy.AccountId : oneV.CreatedBy.Contact.AccountId),
                ShareType = 'I',
                Visibility = 'InternalUsers'
                ));
            }
        }
```

And the test class :

```
// Create Account
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Name = 'Test Account';
insert acc;
        
// Create Contact
Contact ct = new Contact();
ct.FirstName = 'Alphonse';
ct.LastName = 'Brown';
ct.Email = 'alph.borwn@mail.com';
ct.AccountId = acc.Id;
insert ct;
        
// Create Portal User
Profile startupperProfile = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = :System.Label.My_Profile_Name];
User portalUser = new User();
portalUser.ProfileId = startupperProfile.Id;
portalUser.Username ='alph.borwn@mail.com';
portalUser.Alias = 'alphi';
portalUser.Email='alph.borwn@mail.com';
portalUser.EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8';
portalUser.Firstname='Alphonse';
portalUser.Lastname='Brown';
portalUser.LanguageLocaleKey='en_US';
portalUser.LocaleSidKey='en_US';
portalUser.TimeZoneSidKey='Europe/Berlin';
portalUser.ContactId = ct.Id;
insert portalUser;
    
ContentVersion cv;
System.runAs ( portalUser ){
       NetworkMember membership = [SELECT NetworkID, MemberID FROM NetworkMember WHERE memberID = :portalUser.id];

       // Create File
       cv = new ContentVersion();
       cv.Title = 'test';
       cv.PathOnClient = 'test.pdf';
       cv.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('Test Data');
       cv.NetworkId = membership.NetworkId;
       insert cv;
}

List<ContentDocumentLink> docLinks = [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink
                                    WHERE ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersionId = :cv.Id
                                    AND LinkedEntityId = :acc.Id];
System.assertEquals(1, docLinks.size(), 'Document should be linked to the Account');
```

Any help ?